# Counting the Days from the current_level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

There are 5 levels.

Each level has a certain amount of days in it that must pass before the habit can move up to the next level (as broken down by `n_days`):

```
      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3  #Level 3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            "Mastery"
         end
      end
```

How can we call the `n_days` from the present level in the habits index with something like `<%= habit.current_level.n_days.count_off_from_zero_to_show %>`?

For example, if we are specifically at `50` on level 3 it would show Day 5 in the habits index.

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday } - self.missed_days

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            "Mastery"
        end
    end
end
```

**level.rb**

```
class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :habit
end
```

**schema**

```
create_table "habits", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "missed_days",    default: 0
  t.text     "committed"
  t.integer  "days_lost",   default: 0
  t.datetime "date_started"
  t.string   "trigger"
  t.string   "target"
  t.string   "reward"
  t.boolean  "private_submit"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  t.integer  "order"
end

add_index "habits", ["user_id", "created_at"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id_and_created_at"
add_index "habits", ["user_id"], name: "index_habits_on_user_id"

create_table "levels", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "habit_id"
  t.integer  "days_lost",   default: 0
  t.integer  "missed_days",   default: 0
  t.integer  "current_level"
  t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
end

add_index "levels", ["habit_id"], name: "index_levels_on_habit_id"
```

The **Gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Comment: I think you're providing more code than is necessary to explain your problem. I would recommend refining the question to be a bit more specific. I think I understand though, and I'll try and provide an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `current_level` method you've got two lines of logic that ultimately represent the value of `n_days`. If you want to reuse that value outside of that method or case statement, you should either store the value in an instance variable, or move the logic into another method. If the logic is only important to this class, then I might make it a private method.

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Existing code ... 

  private

  def committed_wdays
    committed.map do |day|    
      Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize)
    end
  end

  def n_days
    ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count do |date| 
      committed_wdays.include? date.wday
    end - self.missed_days
  end
end
```

The private methods can be further refined, but hopefully this gives you an idea of how you might continue to extract the shared logic.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I put your methods under the current_level (in place of my `=` code) instead of putting it under private. Seems to work. Can you think of any negative ramifications of that alternative?

Comment: Also your current code calls all `n_days` instead of only from the present level so for example if I'm 30 days into the habit I don't want to show 30, I want to show 5 because we are 5 days into level 3. Am I making more sense? Is that possible?

Comment: If you're still looking into this, not including `private` is fine, but it's a way of restricting access to methods that should only be used inside of your class and not referenced from other objects.

Comment: Okay awesome thanks for getting back to me @kevinthompson :) Do you know a way I could just call how many days passed in the `current_level`? Is that a hard leap from what you got? For example calling `f.current_level` will get the exact level number so either 1 - 5. Calling `f.n_days` will give how many total days has passed since start of habit. Calling `f.current_level.n_days` gives undefined method `n_days`