# undefined local variable or method `n_days' when calling case variable in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, model

In my habit model I created a new method:

```
def current_level_days
  current_level[n_days]
end
```

How can we call the case variable of `n_days` in the new method so that I can achieve my larger goal of [Counting the Days from the current_level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067159/counting-the-days-from-the-current-level)

**habit.rb**

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, as: :commentable
    has_many :levels
    serialize :committed, Array
    validates :date_started, presence: true
    before_save :current_level
    acts_as_taggable
    scope :private_submit, -> { where(private_submit: true) }
    scope :public_submit, -> { where(private_submit: false) }

attr_accessor :missed_one, :missed_two, :missed_three

    def save_with_current_level
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.levels.build
        self.save
    end

    def self.committed_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end 

    def current_level_strike
      levels[current_level - 1] # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level_days
      current_level(:n_days) # remember arrays indexes start at 0
    end

    def current_level
            return 0 unless date_started
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday } - self.missed_days

      case n_days     
          when 0..9
            1
          when 10..24
            2
          when 25..44
            3
          when 45..69
            4
          when 70..99
            5
          else
            "Mastery"
        end
    end
end
```

The **Gist** of it: https://gist.github.com/RallyWithGalli/c66dee6dfb9ab5d338c2

Thank you so much for your expertise!

Comment: `n_days` is scoped to the `current_level`method which only returns one of those values in case. as soon as it returns `n_days` falls out of scope. Also `current_level` does not accept arguments so you will get an `ArgumentError` if you want `n_days` to be accessible either build it out as a method and reference it where needed or create it as an instance variable and reference it. Also `current_level` does not return an `Array` it returns a string or Integer so `current_level[n_days]` will end up being a single letter,`nil`, or the the case of an integer this will be a bit reference 0 or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access `n_days` in `current_level_days` because it hasn't been declared, hence the undefined. Up at the top of your class add:

`attr_accessor n_days` and you should be good to go.

Unless it's stored in your database somewhere? I'm sorry it's not clear.

However, if it is stored in the table, you should be able to access it with `self.n_days` so `current_level(self.n_days)` should work in that instance

Comment: as a note `current_level` does not accept arguments so you will get an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`